# Как передать массив данных во фрагментный шейдер?

Tags: массивы, opengl

Требуется передать некоторый объем данных формата int во фрагментный шейдер, на основании которых шейдер определял бы какую из текстур ему использовать. Пробовал задействовать TBO для подобных целей:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture1);
texLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramId,"Tex1 ");
glUniform1i(texLoc,0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture2);
texLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramId,"Tex2 ");
glUniform1i(texLoc,1);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture3);
texLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramId,"Tex3");
glUniform1i(texLoc,2);

glGenBuffers(1, &FTexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, FTexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, sizeof(array_id),array_id,
                    GL_STREAM_DRAW);

glGenTextures(1, &FBuffer);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, FBuffer);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); 
glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_R32I, FTexBuffer);

glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER,FBuffer);
texLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramId,"tex_id ");
glUniform1i(texLoc,3);
```

Фрагментный шейдер:

```
out vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D Tex1;
uniform sampler2D Tex2;
uniform sampler2D Tex3;
uniform isamplerBuffer tex_id;
in vec2 Tex_coord;

void main()
{
   if (texelFetchBuffer(tex_id,1) == 3)
        color = texture(tex1, tex_coord);
   if (texelFetchBuffer(tex_id,5) == 4)
        color = texture(tex2, tex_coord);
   if (texelFetchBuffer(tex_id,25) == 5)
        color = texture(tex3, tex_coord);\n"\
…

}
```

Ничего не вышло. В чём проблема? Содержимое массива array_id весьма слабо влияет на конечный исход, а после нескольких экспериментов с кодом содержимое массива и вовсе перестало как-либо сказываться на результате. Судя по всему данные в шейдер просто не передаются.

Comment: То что вы делаете в этом шейдере крайне паршивая идея. Соберите все ваши текстуры в одну большую картинку(текстурный атлас) алгоритмом MAXRECTS с BL эвристикой и используйте пересчитанные UV координаты для навигации по ней, таким образом в шейдере не нужно будет вообще ничего переключать и вы получите свою анимированную текстуру простым выбором нужных данных из VBO в котором хранятся текстурные координаты.

Comment: "Соберите все ваши текстуры в одну большую картинку" 
этого как раз и не хотелось бы. Текстуры могут быть разного размера, их не так просто объединить в одну. Для моих задач это совсем не нужно, хотя как вариант - уже давно был оставлен на запас. Анимированные текстуры мне не нужны....  
Вопрос всё же следует акцентрировать на передачи массивов данных в шейдер, так как в любом случае для моих задач он необходим.

Comment: Тут у вас четверый OpenGL похоже, я сейчас работаю с ES 2.0, но вроде они не сильно различаются. Чтобы передать что-то напрямую во фрагментный шейдер нужно использовать текстуру цвет пикселей которой является вашими данными, либо выход вертексного подать во вход пиксельного(фрагментного), а на вход вертексного через uniform или attribute(in) подать то что нужно, предварительно закэшировав в VBO.

Comment: Чтобы передать текстуру необходимо привести её к соответствующему виду, что не очень удобно. Для таких целей вроде бы и создан TBO - чтобы передать одномерный массив в шейдер. Но что-то не работает... весь код перерыл.

Comment: Да я прочитал про TBO в ES вообще нету этой фичи, может проще залить это просто через массив uniform если объем не очень большой.